# Return latest value from the array of duplicate objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array of objects like below,

```
[    
    {time: 1526577280000, operationType: "CREATE", path: "users/111"},
    {time: 1526563418000, operationType: "DELETE", path: "users/111"},
    {time: 1526557418000, operationType: "CREATE", path: "users/111"},
    {time: 1526557280000, operationType: "CREATE", path: "users/123"},
    {time: 1526557223000, operationType: "CREATE", path: "users/345"},
    {time: 1526553596000, operationType: "DELETE", path: "users/222"},
    {time: 1526553444000, operationType: "CREATE", path: "users/222"}
]
```

How can I return only the latest single path from the duplicate paths, based on the latest `timestamp` i.e. `time`. Some objects have same paths that is based upon the operationType and I only want to return the latest path from the object that have multiple number of same paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to define when entries are *duplicates*. The way I understand it, their `operationType` **and** `path` need to be equal, but the `time` can differ. This gives us:

```
const equal = (x, y) => (
  x.operationType === y.operationType &&
  x.path === y.path
);
```

Now, when looping over all entries, we don't necessarily want to check *all other entries* for equality. That's why we'll use a different way to keep track of our progress. We'll define a `hash` function that serializes the objects to a comparable string:

```
const hash = e => [e.operationType, e.path].join("__");
```

Now, we can loop over our data *once* and check if the entry is either the first of a hash, or older than the previous one:

```js
const data = [    
    {time: 1526577280000, operationType: "CREATE", path: "users/111"},
    {time: 1526563418000, operationType: "DELETE", path: "users/111"},
    {time: 1526557418000, operationType: "CREATE", path: "users/111"},
    {time: 1526557280000, operationType: "CREATE", path: "users/123"},
    {time: 1526557223000, operationType: "CREATE", path: "users/345"},
    {time: 1526553596000, operationType: "DELETE", path: "users/222"},
    {time: 1526553444000, operationType: "CREATE", path: "users/222"}
];

const hash = e => [e.operationType, e.path].join("__");
const latestUniques = Object.values(data.reduce(
  (map, e) => {
    const key = hash(e);
    
    if (!map[key] || map[key].time > e.time) {
      map[key] = e;
    }
    
    return map;
    
  },
  {}
));

console.log(latestUniques);
```

Comment: This is close to want I wanted. But the path should also not be repeated and should return only the latest one, i.e. if the path is repeated, I would like to return the latest path no matter the operationType is.

Comment: Change the `hash` function to `e => e.path` and you'll end up with the latest operation for each unique path. That's the benefit of clearly separating these concerns in advance.

Comment: Thank you... I need to change the > sign to < for me to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
array.sort( function(one, two){ return one.time < two.time } )[0].path;
```